# ODM: The domain on the element contains an invalid entry

Tags: ibm-odm

I'm getting the following error when trying to synchronize a dynamic domain retrieved from the database:

*The domain on the element '[domain object]' contains an invalid entry: '[entry]'.*

This only seems to happen for values that start with digits or non alpha characters. Here are my domain values:

[image]

And these are the errors:

[image]

Note that only the first two domain entries result in errors. Are there restrictions to what names can be used for dynamic domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain item names follow the same rules as for Java variable names:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

You can start with something like this:

```
public String normalize(String str) {
    String result = str;
    if (Pattern.matches("^\\d\\w*$", result)) {
        result = "_" + result;
    }
    return result.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "_");
}
```

... to remove non letter/number characters from your item names, and prefix them with an underscore in the case where they start with a number, as in your example.